# Searchkick `all` for multiple arrays with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I need to build a boolean query with searchkick which will check multiple arrays and condition must be true if all elements of an array exist.

I wants records which contains `["2019-11-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-07"]` all dates from one array **OR** from second array `["2019-11-08", "2019-11-09", "2019-11-10"]`

it works perfectly for one array like this.

```
available_on: { all: ["2019-11-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-07"] }
```

I need something like this

```
available_on: { or: { all: ["2019-11-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-07"] , all: ["2019-11-08", "2019-11-09", "2019-11-10"]} }
```

> how can we create a query available_on = A OR B

1. A, B are arrays and we need to match all elements of arrays
2. available_on is target term (also an array in index)

Comment: how can we create a query A OR B, where A, B are arrays and we need to match all elements of arrays @sawa

Comment: Did you tried like this `available_on: {or: [[["2019-11-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-07"], ["2019-11-08", "2019-11-09", "2019-11-10"]]]}`

Comment: it returns records which have even only one date, it considers OR operator between dates of an array `["2019-11-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-07"]`. record with only `2019-11-05` availability will be fetched

Comment: @SikandarTariq Not sure, You wants records which contains `["2019-11-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-07"]` all dates from one array **OR** from second array `["2019-11-08", "2019-11-09", "2019-11-10"]`.

Comment: @MayurShah yes exactly

Comment: @SikandarTariq Try this one `Model.search where: {field_name: ["2019-11-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-07"], or: [[{field_name: ["2019-11-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-07"]]]}`

Comment: will not work, as if you may see searchkick documentation, it will search with `IN` operator in an array unless we use `all` key word

Comment: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#querying

Comment: @SikandarTariq Okay, Try this one `Model.search where: {field_name: {all: ["2019-11-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-07"]}, _or: [field_name: {all: ["2019-11-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-07"]}]}`

Answer (score 4):

You should use `where` with `or` filter like this:

```
where {or: [[{available_on: {all: ["2019-11-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-07"]}},
             {available_on: {all: ["2019-11-08", "2019-11-09", "2019-11-10"]}}]]}
```

or use `_or` filter:

```
where {_or: [{available_on: {all: ["2019-11-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-07"]}},
              available_on: {all: ["2019-11-08", "2019-11-09", "2019-11-10"]}]}
```

There's no difference of results between `_or` and `or`, just a little different in syntax(`or` use one more pair square brackets)

Comment: what is the difference between `_or` and simple `or`? any idea?

Comment: @SikandarTariq just a litter different between them.

Comment: thanks, @Gentry Chen! I'm trying your solution... feels like it will work.

Comment: @SikandarTariq if you want to know how do they work, you should read source code of searchkick

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this inside 'where' clause ?

```
_or: [{available_on: {all: ["2019-11-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-07"]}}, {available_on: {all: ["2019-11-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-07"]}} ]}
```